# Настройка линии текста CSS

Tags: css

Как сделать чтобы при переносе строки, текст начинался с краю,  а не по центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикрепите пожалуйста фрагмент разметки, и стили для этих элементов

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скриншоты кода

Comment: Все равно данных недостаточно. Проинспектируйте элемент .date или его родительский элемент в браузере, посмотрите применненые стили - думаю вы сможете разобраться

Comment: минус за издевательства скриншотами. Вы должны быть заинтересованы в том, чтобы Вам дали правильный ответ, поэтому будьте добры, откройте снипет и впихните туда рабочий пример вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Два способа

1) Абсолютное позиционирование

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  tyransform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>21 сентября <br>в 21:30</p>
</div>
```

2) Flexbox

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>21 сентября <br>в 21:30</p>
</div>
```